# numerical overflow

Tags: sql

I have a field in my SQL database which has a data type of Decimal(2, 2). The problem is when I try to insert data i.e. 5 or -5 in this field I get database error `(314)` which is numerical overflow. I don't know why I'm getting that error.

Comment: Please show us the code that you're having trouble with, and show the exact error message you're getting.  Cut & paste the error message without paraphrasing it.

Comment: "SAP" tag is meaningless. What "SQL database" is your SAP system connected to, please?

Answer (score 1):

`DECIMAL(2, 2)` only allows a range of -0.99 to 0.99

`DECIMAL(X, Y)`

X = Precision (Number of significant digits)
Y = Scale (Number of digits after decimal point)

For example `DECIMAL(5, 2)` would give the range between:
-999.99 to 999.99.

Answer (score 0):

`Decimal(2,2)` commonly means "Two digits of significance, two digits to the right of the decimal point", meaning that such a field can contain value which range from 0 to .99, positive or negative. Thus, 5 is out of range for such a field.

If you wanted to store a single-digit integer such as 5 in a decimal field while also allowing up to two digits to the right of the decimal point you'd have to define the field as `Decimal(3, 2)`, or in other words "Three total significant digits, two of them to the right of the decimal place".